# React router 1.0 - Issue with history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0 rc, and I'm having a bit of an issue with the history. I'm using `createBrowserHistory()`, when I do route transitions, I'm using `pushState` and `replaceState` which is working in the address bar, but not reloading the page, and hard refreshes on any page appends the #/?_k=789x0c to the url, which makes me think the app isn't using history correctly.

I've got a bit too much code to post, but the below should be enough to see how I'm using history (same as most examples really).

history.js:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

index.js:

```
import history from './history';

React.render(
  <Provider store={store} history={history}>
    {() => <Router>{routes}</Router> }
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

Comment: i think, that reloading and rerendering must be apply by react, if you need to catch a hash changing look "hashchange" event

Comment: It's using the history library though, it shouldn't be doing any hash changes, it should be using pushstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with something similar, the issue was caused by placing the history prop on `<Provider>` component instead of `<Router>`, a stupid mistake that was a side effect of migrating to 1.0.